# Report Total Amount Incorrect

Tags: civireport

I setup a report to list contributions from a specific page.  I had to edit the contributions to change the financial type, so now each contribution has 3 line items.  The "Total Amount" on my report is now adding all 3 line items for each donation.

Is there a way to tell the report to total just the amount and not each line item?

[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about which report (template) you're using? Chances are, a different report might be a better fit for you.

Comment: @AlanDixon I'm using the "Contribution Detail Report" with a filter for the specific contribution page

Comment: In fact, both the Detail and Summary reports in the Contributions section are "Donor" reports, not "Contributions", which adds an extra complexity. I'd recommend you try the summary one, and if that doesn't give you what you need, try the "extended reports" extension (which will give you all kinds of things you don't want and didn't know anyone might ever want).